# White Hole Formation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, white-holes

How does a white hole form in nature if it were to exist? No knowledge of general relativity or advanced mathematics but doing a researching a physics project and need a basic explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A white hole *isn't* formed. This is the *definition*. If $t$ is cosmic time, then a white hole is black hole that existed at $t=-\infty$.

Take a look at this Penrose diagram. (Ignore the parallel universe piece.)
[image]
The corner where $r=0$ and $r=\infty$ meets is called the past timelike infinity. We see that the white hole existed at that time. For a universe that does not have a beginning (for example no Big Bang), the white hole has *always existed*.

Comment: So basically what are the conditions which need to be satisfied which would permit a white hole coming into existance?

Comment: The point is that they *don't come into existence*. The question you should is asking is, "What are the conditions that allow white holes to exist?" I don't think we know a definite answer. (At least I don't.) There are some modern theories which suggest the Big Bang is itself a white hole.

Comment: I've heard though people going on about "eternal" black holes amongst other things. What's all that about?

Comment: An eternal black hole is a white hole. It used to be that white holes were eternal black holes, but the definition might have been broadened recently.

Comment: Another way of putting it is that a white hole can be thought of as a certain kind of initial condition.

Comment: @AlbertEinsteinJnr. for a discussion of eternal black holes see the question [Eternal Black Holes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161458/eternal-black-holes)